# Парные элементы массива

Tags: массивы

Дана задача:

Вам нужно создать массив и заполнить его случайными числами от 1 до 100 (ф-я rand). Далее, вычислить произведение тех элементов, которые больше ноля и у которых парные индексы. После вывести на экран элементы, которые больше ноля и у которых не парный индекс.

Вопрос не в коде, а в подходе=)
Собственно не понятно само задание. Что значит парные элементы массива? 
Я считаю, что это элементы с индексами 11,22,33,44,55 и т.д. то есть числа индекса образуют пару. Но мой друг и весь интернет говорят, что это числа у которых остаток от деления на 2 = 0, то есть это ЧЕТНЫЕ ЧИСЛА ! Кто решал такую задачку, как это правильно.
По мне, парный это остаток деления на 11 = 0. 66/11 = 6.0

Comment: Парный это скорее всего [ошибочный перевод](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=ru&tl=uk&text=%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) с украинского. Там схожее слово означает именно четный. отсюда и путаница.

Comment: Спасибо =) Тогда задача выглядит более тривиально )